# Vue JS 2: Bind computed property to data attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a data object in Vue.js 2 that looks like this:

```
data: {
     items: [
          {
            value1: 10, 
            value2: 10,
            valuesum: ""
          },
          {
            value1: 10, 
            value2: 100,
            valuesum: "",
          }
     ]
```

I render that data object in a table and run calculations on it. I want the `valuesum` property to be computed and stored in each object somehow. In other words, I want the code to essentially perform this:

```
data: {
     items: [
          {
            value1: 10, 
            value2: 10,
            valuesum: {{ value1 + value2 }} //20
          },
          {
            value1: 10, 
            value2: 100,
            valuesum: {{ value1 + value2 }} //110
          }
     ]
```

The `computed` attribute doesn't seem to be able to accomplish this. I tried to use the following function but this does not work:

```
 function (index) {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++ ){
                return this.items[index].value1 + this.items[index].value2;
            }
        }
```

The closest I have managed to get to an answer is by doing the calculation inline, but I can't bind its result to the `items.total` object. My HTML looks like this:

```
<table id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Value 1</td>
                <td>Value 2</td>
                <td>Sum</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="item in items">
                <td><input type="number" v-model="item.value1"></td>
                <td><input type="number" v-model="item.value2"></td>
                <td> {{ item.value1 + item.value2 }} </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

But I can't add `v-model` to it, since it's not an input. I'd like to avoid adding a readonly `<input>` to the column, since that doesn't seem like the best solution and isn't very elegant.

Comment: any special reason why you want to store it in a state? ideally, we should only keep minimum required data in the state and derive everything we can the way you are doing.

Comment: I'd like to add each data object to a database after some user input. I wondered if Vue had its own method for storing calculations, so I don't have to do the same calculation when I call each object later.

Comment: You can make use of `watch` and then change the total when either of your value change.

Comment: Can you put the `data` part into the computed section (i.e. static content)? Otherwise, just create a computed copy of the data attribute and add the calculated stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few approaches: Binding to a method, binding to a computed property, and binding to a data property that is saved during the computed property call:

```
  <table id="table">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <td>Value 1</td>
           <td>Value 2</td>
           <td>Sum</td>
           <td>Sum</td>
           <td>Sum</td>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(item, index) in items">
           <td><input type="number" v-model="item.value1"></td>
           <td><input type="number" v-model="item.value2"></td>
           <td> {{ sum(item) }} </td><!-- method -->
           <td> {{ sums[index] }}</td><!-- computed -->
           <td> {{ item.valuesum }}</td><!-- data property via computed -->
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

The script:

```
var vm = new Vue({
   el: "#table",
   data: function () {
      return {
         items: [
            {
               value1: 10, 
               value2: 10,
               valuesum: 0
            },{
               value1: 10, 
               value2: 100,
               valuesum: 0,
            }
         ]
      }
   },

   computed: {
      sums: function () {
         var val = [];
         for (var index in this.items) {
            var sum = this.sum(this.items[index]);
            val.push(sum);

            // Update the local data if you want
            this.items[index].valuesum = sum;
         }
         return val;
      }
   },

   methods: {
      sum: function (item) {
         // Alternate, if you take valuesum out:
         // for (var prop in item) {
         //    val += parseInt(item[prop]);
         // }
         return parseInt(item.value1) + parseInt(item.value2);
      }
   }
});
```

Is that the sort of thing you're looking for?